# Associating user data between multiple passport strategies

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I'm using node, express, express-session, mongoose and passport-discord to authenticate users. But I also wish to use passport-steam to optionally link a user's steam account to their discord account.

The problem is, in order to link their steam account, I would also need a way of knowing which discord user is trying to do so, but the authentication callback doesn't include any request/response headers to access the current session, and the database I'm storing discord users in doesn't have any steam data in it until steam's authentication callback is called, at which point I have no idea which discord user is trying to authenticate their steam account.

To help remedy this, I've setup 3 mongoose models to have 3 separate database collections:

- DiscordUser (stores discord user information, including their discordId)
- SteamUser (stores steam user information, including their steamId)
- User (stores required discordId and optional steamId)

I then try to serialize and deserialize the User object, but the `passport.deserializeUser(obj, done)` method seems to pass in an id instead of a User object, and I can't be sure if it's a discordId or a steamId, or which discord user I'm deserializing a SteamUser for, so I end up back at square one.

What's the best way to go about associating these users?
If needed, I can supply some code snippets upon request.

Answer (score 0):

I [found an article](https://codeburst.io/account-linking-with-passportjs-in-3-minutes-2cb1b09d4a76) which helped solve this problem.
Here's what I did to fix it:

- Using `passReqToCallback: true` in the `new Strategy(...)` options
- In both strategy callback functions, adding `req` as the first parameter
  (ie., `async function callback(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) { ... }`)

And then changing this:

```
router.get('/steam', passport.authenticate('steam'), (req, res) => {
  //...
});
```

To this:

```
// Note that the route here is the same as the callback/redirect
router.get('/steam/redirect', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('steam', (err, user, { nextRoute }) => {
    if (err)
      return next(err);

    if (nextRoute) {
      // user was authorized with provider?
      // send em back to profile
      return res.redirect(nextRoute);
    } else {
      // give em some cookies
      req.logIn(user, err => {
        if (err)
          return next(err);

        return res.redirect('/');
      });
    }
  })(req, res, next)
});
```

And then finally, modifying the `User` model schema to include the `sessionID`, which can be accessed via `req.sessionID` *(or `req.session.sessionID`)* from within the callback functions of both strategies.

This allows me to update the database upon successful login with my primary strategy(s) (discord, in this case), and then reference it from secondary strategies (steam, in this case), providing enough time to update the `User` database to have linked information between each strategy for as long as the session is still valid. After which, you can always simply reference the `User` database anywhere in code to check for valid primary *and* secondary strategy ids, allowing you to cross-reference other database collections for information, update the session id if the current session id doesn't match (and possibly forcing the user to re-authenticate?), etc.